# Angular CLI 1.7.4 TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null

Tags: angular-cli

Just downgraded global CLI from Angular 6 to Angular 5, so running CLI 1.7.4

Attempting to ng serve on a project originally created for Ang 5 (but downgraded dependencies for Ang 6) I'm getting error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null

at Class.run (/Users/me/git-projects/wra-starter-ng5/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js:51:63)
at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (/Users/me/git-projects/wra-starter-ng5/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve.js:123:26)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

My ng --version shows:

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 10.2.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cdk: 5.2.5
@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular/flex-layout: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular/material: 5.2.5
@angular/upgrade: 5.2.1
@angular-devkit/architect: 0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular: 0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core: 0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 6.0.8
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.6.2
webpack: 4.8.3
```

Looking for possible causes, I'm guessing something in the project's package.json is not compatible with CLI 1.7.4 (this project was originally written for Angular 6)

Here's the line in tasks/serve.js its complaining about (config is null):

```
    const projectConfig = config_1.CliConfig.fromProject().config;
```

NOTE: My project has an angular.json but not an angular-cli.json. Renaming the angular.json to angular-cli.json and borrowing contents from a similar project known to work under 1.7.4 CLI throws many errors.

Here are errors I'm seeing now on ng serve with a default angular-cli.json in project:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: Error: Angular Compiler was detected but it was an instance of the wrong class.
This likely means you have several @ngtools/webpack packages installed. You can check this with `npm ls @ngtools/webpack`, and then remove the extra copies.
    at Object.ngcLoader (/Users/me/git-projects/wra-starter-ng5/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:33:15)
ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed: Error: Angular Compiler was detected but it was an instance of the wrong class.
This likely means you have several @ngtools/webpack packages installed. You can check this with `npm ls @ngtools/webpack`, and then remove the extra copies.
    at Object.ngcLoader (/Users/me/git-projects/wra-starter-ng5/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:33:15)
ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/me/git-projects/wra-starter-ng5/src/styles.css' in '/Users/me/git-projects/wra-starter-ng5'
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.
node_modules/@ruf/shell/node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.
src/app/app.module.ts(7,10): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/me/git-projects/wra-starter-ng5/node_modules/@ruf/shell/ruf-shell"' has no exported member 'RufShellModule'.
```

Answer (score 0):

We've faced the same issue recently with 1.7.4.

first try `./node_modules/.bin/ng init` (fixed issue for couple of times)

You'll need to do is check your **node_modules/angular/cli/models/config.ts** file.

Search for this line on the code

```
export const CLI_CONFIG_FILE_NAME = '.angular-cli.json';
```

Make sure there is a "." in front of of the angular-cli.json on this file. At times there are some issues on cli that doesn't add the relative file name.

Reference - (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4736#issuecomment-280404750)

Once you verified that,

you'll need to remove your node_modules folder from your project.

and then run `npm remove webpack`

remove package-lock.json file.

```
npm cache clean --force

npm install @angular/cli@1.7.4
```

run `npm install again`

finally check if you find any dependency mismatches `npm ls --depth 0`

run npm start or ng serve.

If you want to do this hard way, you can create new angular cli project, copy your package.json files, src folder, angular-cli.json, and env configs onto the new project.

It should fix the issue as well.

Comment: Is your project with angular6? Are you running a angular 6 project with angular-cli.json instead of angular.json?

Comment: angular cli anything below v6 is Angular 2 - Angular 5. We are using cli v1.7.4 that spins-up Angular V5.